# What does the $p$ in the formular $dU=Tds-pdV$ refer to?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, notation

In Callen's book (Thermodynamics and an I, second edition)p36 2.6 Based on what he said above, it seems like $p$ is the intensity of pressure inside the system.
but when I asked my friend, he said the $p$ is the pressure of the environment outside the system .
I was totally confused. Do I mix up two different things?
For example, in free expansion， what does the $p$ in $Tds-Pdv=0$ refer to? Isn't the gas doing no work to the outside world
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This equation applies to the change between two neighboring equilibrium states, and, in an equilibrium state, the inside pressure and environment pressure are equal.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that some of the confusion arises because the equation assumes a constant pressure and constant temperature in the change in internal energy. In real systems this is not typical. However, in an idealized system the equation shows that the internal energy is sensitive to a change in volume and entropy.

The purpose of the equation is designed to relate work to heat where mechanical work is based on a change in volume of a constant pressure system and heat is related to the change in entropy in a constant temperature system.  This is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy#Internal_energy_of_a_closed_thermodynamic_system).

While having a truly constant pressure system is not typical, you have to contextualize the development of these relationships as it relates to the operation of a steam engine in the 18th and 19th century.  In that context, you can imagine mechanical work in terms of a steam engine consisting of a capped cylinder and piston where the piston is free to move.  If I introduce steam into the cylinder at some constant pressure it will force the piston to move.  The displacement of the piston is a measure of work, however this displacement has increased the internal volume.

Similarly, if I have a source of steam that is maintained at a constant temperature, in order to change the heat in that system you change the internal entropy.  This is a harder concept to grasp but is roughly understood as what happens at the point where water starts to boil.  The heat of vaporization (or sometimes called the [enthalpy of vaporization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization)) represents this condition.  Here the temperature of the water/steam stays relatively constant as heat is added.  The overall change in internal energy is directly related to the change in the system's entropy. Understanding this was important since in the early days of steam you almost always dealt with a mixed state of water and steam so understanding the useful work you might get out of the mixed state was important.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: No, you are not correct in referring to the historical operating context. The true reason is coming from a theoretical understanding of the practical realities. What Carnot realised is that the understanding of any heat engine is only sensible after having a way to understand reversible processes, to compare real engines with them. To get reversibility, you have to be quasistatic, and that is the true reason for always working with well-defined pressures and temperatures. It is not about constancy. It is about well-defined-ness.

Comment: @naturallyconsistent Newcomen engines had been operating 80 years before Carnot was born, Carnot may have built a framework for analyzing them but the motivation is clear, even the wikipedia article on Carnot opens with "Driven by purely technical concerns, such as improving the performance of the steam engine, Sadi Carnot's theoretical work laid important foundations for modern science as well as technologies such as the automobile and jet engine."https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Léonard_Sadi_Carnot

Comment: Carnot clearly had that motivation; that does not change the correctness of what I was saying. It is precisely because of his motivation that he needed to get a proper theoretical understanding, as opposed to the practical, historical, operating context.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I think we might be talking past each other.